# A simple Riccati equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Riccati equation is 
$$
-\dot p=1-p^2(1-\gamma^{-2}), \quad p(T)=\delta,
$$
where $\gamma$ is just a constant. I tried the two methods given in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation). The first one is to transform it into a second order linear ODE. But then I don't have enough initial conditions. The second is to first find a particular solution and then transform it into a Bernoulli equation. However I failed to identify a particular solution. Could anyone help me?

Comment: This is not, strictly speaking, a Ricatti equation. This equation is separable and can be easily integrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To continue my comment:
$$
\dot p=Ap^2-1\implies \\
\frac{dp}{Ap^2-1}=dt\implies\\
\ldots
$$